HP Victus F5 mute key LED not working
I'm using Debian 12 KDE version on my HP Victus laptop with dual booted with windows 11 and the mute key LED is not working but the mute function when pressing that key works properly on linux regardless of any distro or Desktop Environment I previously used like debian, ubuntu, mint, manjaro, Endeavour OS, etc. But other LEDs in keys like caps lock, F11(to toggle touchpad), power button works properly. the F5 key's LED works when I'm on my Windows 11 but if I boot into linux it won't work no matter what distro I use. I also used few Linux distros alone as my main OS without windows installed(no dual boot), even in that case it won't work on linux. I have no idea on how to make it work, all I can guess is it is a driver related problem so I tried searching for the keyboard driver's source code that is used by my system to take a look at it but couldn't find it. Is there any way to make the LED work?
Cases when the F5 LED works Properly:

Windows alone(no dual boot)
Window dual booted with linux, regardless of distro type

Cases when the F5 LED not works:

Linux alone(no dual boot)
Linux alongside with windows 10/11

Note: All other working LEDs in the laptop's Keyboard is white coloured and all working fine all the above cases except the LED of F5 key is Orange colour.

Sorry about the question's clarity, I've improved the question with additional details. to summarize it only works on Windows no matter I'm in dual boot with linux or windows only environment it works, and it never works on linux regardless of any distro neither on dual boot nor on linux only environment.

Thank you for clarifying. It is indeed a software/OS issue.

Thank you for your reply, regardless of this issue I wanted to find the source code of the keyboard driver that is used by linux for my system, any Idea on how to find the source code of the keyboard driver?
